# Converting CDialog to CPropertyPage

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using an example for the coding in my project. Now I have the problem, that in the example they use the CDialog class, but I need a CProperyPage class. How do I convert from CDialog to CPropertypage?
Here my code:

```
.cpp File:
CNativeCallerDlg::CNativeCallerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CPropertyPage(CNativeCallerDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

.h File:
// CNativeCallerDlg dialog
class CNativeCallerDlg : public CPropertyPage
{
// Construction
public:
    CNativeCallerDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor
    enum { IDD = 102 };
}
```

Original:

```
.cpp
CNativeCallerDlg::CNativeCallerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CNativeCallerDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

.h
class CNativeCallerDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CNativeCallerDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor
    enum { IDD = 102 };
}
```

As you can see, my code can't use the CPropertyPage(CNativeCallerDlg::IDD, pParent) since there is no funktion with this kind of input.

Can I still use the CDialog(CNativeCallerDlg::IDD, pParent) instead and convert it to CPropertyPage?

Thanks

Comment: Have you consulted the MSDN documentation?  Everything you need is explained there.

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
CNativeCallerDlg::CNativeCallerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CPropertyPage(CNativeCallerDlg::IDD)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: In the end I found a way to use the original way instead, so I can't say if what you wrote is the answer.